# Unable to change background color of a visited link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color of a visited link, but the CSS I am using doesn't work. It would be great if someone could help me.
I have tried an important tag too, but still, the background color does not change.

```css
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fragment:visited { text-decoration: line-through; }
.fragment:hover {background-color:#f7f7f7; text-decoration: none;}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.styleraise { 
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
} 

.styleraise1 { 
    color: green;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 6px;
    float:right;
}

.textpara {
    color:grey;
}

.imgbor {
border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<a class="fragment" href="google.com" target="_blank">
    <div>
    <img class="imgbor" src ="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NfU6VKEG__Q/V0P5yb-0vkI/AAAAAAAAABU/1ifpBLBKBpAcIdVXNvmbqt_Ygou2bHQdACLcB/s1600/realplayer.jpg" alt="some description"/> 
    <span class="styleraise">Download Real Player</span><span class="styleraise1">Real</span>
    <p class="textpara">
        Download RealPlayer for Free. Watch all your favorite videos. Plus, Download, Save, Organize and Share Videos.
    </p>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: </a> first change this if this is not typo.

Comment: For me, its working. can you please tell which line or text  you want as you give a tag to whole div and div background color is getting change. is this what you want?

Comment: @Leothelion When I hover on it, the background color changes, but I need the background color to change to green, when someone has visited the link.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/ja6s5wLy/

Comment: Please check this- https://jsfiddle.net/ja6s5wLy/1/    When I click on the link it turns red, but when I click on the link below, the above block goes back to it's original color. I want the block to stay red forever for the user.

Comment: Try a:focus{ background:#000099;}, so after click when your cursor is in hover state then it changes your color to grey. But outside of box this #000099.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment on Jainam's answer, a way to change the color of the link to red after click would be the below code.

Please keep in mind that this will only keep the link red as long as someone stays on the page. If they refresh or navigate away and return the link won't be red again.

You could optionally store which links have been clicked in a cookie and then read the cookie when people return to the page, making it red again based on the cookie value.

That or send people to a redirect page which saves the clicked link in a database, then make links red based on which links are stored.

```js
$(".fragment").click(function(){
  $(".fragment").css('background','#FF0000');
});
```

```css
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fragment:visited { text-decoration: line-through; }
.fragment:hover {background-color:#f7f7f7; text-decoration: none;}


.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.styleraise { 
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
} 

.styleraise1 { 
    color: green;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 6px;
    float:right;
}

.textpara {
    color:grey;
}

.imgbor {
border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.fragment:focus, .fragment:visited, .fragment:active {
  background-color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="fragment" href="google.com" target="_blank">
    <div>
    <img class="imgbor" src ="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NfU6VKEG__Q/V0P5yb-0vkI/AAAAAAAAABU/1ifpBLBKBpAcIdVXNvmbqt_Ygou2bHQdACLcB/s1600/realplayer.jpg" alt="some description"/> 
    <span class="styleraise">Download Real Player</span><span class="styleraise1">Real</span>
    <p class="textpara">
        Download RealPlayer for Free. Watch all your favorite videos. Plus, Download, Save, Organize and Share Videos.
    </p>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 first add css

.fragment:visited { text-decoration: line-through; background-color:green;}

<a class="fragment" href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank">
```

In Your hyper link give full url that will be work

First you missed the (fragment:visited) background-color in that class and in your hyper link miss the full url path